# So what would be needed for a name change?

Tags: discussion

There are few meta users, and even I cannot promise to be around much.  My participation is periodic based on clinic scheduling and down time from babysitting fellows.

That said, what would actually need to happen to change the name of the site?  How many up votes would we need?  I'm curious to see if any meaningful amount attention will be held by any meta question given the recent content.

For the record, I'm super pro "MedicalOverflow" as a name.

Comment: I'v just [gone ahead](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/821/8212) and proposed a site name change. Let's see how much it takes