# Rethinking our Site Name

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We have previously discussed that the current site name does lead to the impression that our site might be concerned with *personal health of users*. As this is not the case and we do not want to mislead new users (and deter them by closing their questions), maybe we can rethink our site name.

Below are options of site names. Feel free to think of a name, and post it below as a Community Answer.

Please upvote your favourite proposal!

Comment: I mean my question had a whopping 5 views... even if we get that many votes...

Comment: "Health" also lead me to think that questions about healthcare systems, and doctors were appropriate. My questions about healthcare systems were all closed as off-topic, but my doctor-related question was upvoted, answered, and not suggested for closing. I've now discovered the [on-topic](health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, which leads me to find it strange that the doctor question was not also closed because it doesn't fall under any of the categories on that page.

In addition to a name change, a persistent banner with the on-topic list would be helpful while in beta.

Comment: Agreed:  "a persistent banner with the on-topic list would be helpful while in beta"

Comment: I don't think a name change is going to help. Anyone who finds an SE site with anything remotely related to medicine or health and pays no attention to topic lists is going to ask for medical advice. I personally think we just need more moderators who regularly reviews review queues

Answer (score 7):

### Medical Sciences

**Pro:**

- it isn't misleading regarding personal medical advice
- <s>consistency with our sister-site, CognitiveSciences</s> it is now renamed as *Psychology and Neuroscience*
- represents site scope well
- is very professional

**Cons**

- there's already [an Area51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113814/medical-sciences?tab=active#tab-top) with that name,
  so we would have to figure out what to do with that

Comment: Simply renaming the group might obviate the need for another group. I think the name is 90% of the problem.

Comment: I mean it's a bit drab. I was thinking we might have fun that comes with something like "SuperUser," (again I know it's a proper term), but I don't have any objections to MedicalSciences.  I just think MedicalOverflow is funnier and scientists/doctors tend to be attracted to puns (otherwise we stop using them and assigning punny names whenever the opportunity arises).

Comment: @AtlLED Yes it is. Out of the three alternatives, it’s the best one though IMHO. Feel free to be creative and suggest something a bit more fun (like SU)

Comment: I like this name, in part because I think it would discourage some of the low-quality "I think I have a medical problem please help me" questions.

Answer (score 5):

**Medicine**

To show the shift away from patient oriented ( and thus an endless pit of poor questions ) to a professional orientation.

I don't like Medical Sciences as much of what we do is apply treatments which are a result of science.  But we mostly don't engage in the practice of medical research.

Answer (score 3):

HumanBiology which takes all those human biology questions from biology.se, avoids animal medical questions, and all the current off topic medical treatment questions.

Answer (score -1):

### MedicalOverflow

**Pro:**

- it isn't as misleading regarding personal medical advice
- has a touch of professionalism, like MathOverflow
- represents site scope quite well

**Cons:**

- not as poignant as Health or shorter names

Comment: But it is a pun, programming related and as such for newbies not coming from coding background like StackO … at least a bit mysterious. First impression reading this on a search site will be: weird. The professionalism is only coming apparaent if read within the scope of SE, not from outside of that.

Comment: @LangLangC I don’t get the pun, but maybe that’s just me :)

Comment: Non-coders *will* have missed that: [Pufferüberlauf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pufferüberlauf) What's the positive equivalent for our scope? Seizure? [LedZep](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoqQnR8NOVI)? And I already mentioned it: excluding coding I see pix of plastic bags filling with fluids of all colours and provenances until dripping points.

Comment: @LangLangC I am aware of a stack overflow, I just didn’t have that image of a large supply of medication leaking out every.

Comment: Well – not just medication but "all that stuff": water, urine,  blood, bile, feces,  puss etc. –– Might draw in "specialists".

Comment: @LangLangC Ähem. Maybe not so great of a name I initially thought it would be. I‘m trying to be creative coming up with other possibilities of a name, but it’s pretty difficult. Right now we really only have one realistic alternative, which is MedicalOverflow. There must be some others.

Comment: Well, that's the problem – I saw 'coming' with leetspeak:_ " MedOF". If it's good for initiates->  then well, but drawing fresh blood gets difficult with such inner circel/esotheric language. Recruiting from within SE: Overflow gets a +1. Recruitin from outside: nogo!

Comment: The "overflow" word is 100% a techie programmer thing that normal people will not understand. Terrible choice.

Comment: "Overflow" is something medical pros, especially nurses, have to deal with all the time.  It's a funny pun to be related to the history of Stack Overflow (which is admittedly a proper computer term I haven't had to use since I was undergrad), and tying in a common experience of medical pros exposure to fluids.

Comment: I also don't think you have to understand what a stack overflow is to think MedicalOverflow is a funny/good name.

Comment: @AtlLED Fantastic argument! Nurses and all is actually a very fair point I undervalued;  again. Thx for this perspective correction. (Although I was fixated on this first and had the "real-life flowing" only while name-musing: The geek perspective is imho still universally problematic for the goals here.)

Answer (score -4):

### Health

**Pro:**

- it's all encompassing and shows our brought scope

**Cons:**

- gives the impression of Quora or Yahoo Answers
- doesn't highlight our quality standards
- is misleading regarding the personal medical advice

Comment: I quite strongly believe in going by example. Thename itself is just a *very* rough guide. A much better guide will be the questions and answers accesible to the default page.

Comment: That is: regardless of the name: prior content and the handling of *that* will define the site much more than anything else.